# Setting specific folder for auxiliary files

Tags: folders

Suppose I have a folder with my own style files to create my beamer presentation. Also I have another folder with images that I use for my title page. Is there any way I can set up those folders to pick up the style files and the images. Actually, either I put all my presentations in the same folder with sty files and images or I replicate them for any folder with different presentation. However it is a bit messy. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under linux and Mac Os you can set the `$TEXINPUTS` variable to include the paths to your figures and style files.

Comment: Thanks. I apologize if I did not mention this in my post, but I use Windows.

Comment: Just search for `TEXINPUTS windows` either in this forum or with one of the standard search engines, you'll get several hits.